# IntegrityError in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm playing with DRF and made a simple blog where anonymous people can comment on a blog post. I'm just using the browsable API at the moment, and everything seems to work fine until I try to post a comment. DELETE, GET, and PUT all work as expected, only POST.

The error I get is `IntegrityError at /api/posts/i-had-a-blog-his-name-was-bingo/comments/: blog_comment.blogpost_id may not be NULL`

I've searched thoroughly for an answer as to why this might be happening, but nothing is helping. Here's my code...

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(BlogPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('post-detail', { 'slug': self.slug })
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', 'author', 'content')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.Field(source='blogpost.title')

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'content', 'post')    


class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='post-detail')
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='comment-list')

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'title', 'content', 'owner', 'comments')
```

**views.py**

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return Comment.objects.filter(blogpost__slug=slug)


class CommentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrNoEdit,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return Comment.objects.filter(blogpost__slug=slug)
```

**urls.py**

```
commentpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.CommentList.as_view(), name='comment-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CommentDetail.as_view(), name='comment-detail'),
)


urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^$', 'api_root'),
    url(r'^posts/$', views.PostList.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/comments/', include(commentpatterns)),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you show us what you are POSTing? Since a comment always has to belong to a blogpost from your model, you have to provide the blogpost id when creating a new comment. Which is what it's complaining about.

Comment: I was posting the author and the content, there was no option to send the blogpost id. Again, I'm using the browsable API to test everything. With **andrean**'s answer I'm closer, but it's not setting the blogpost id properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Comment` model defines a `ForeignKey`, which is not allowed to be `null`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments')
    ...
```

which is ok, but your serializer does not include the `blogpost` id, so even if your request includes it, it will be just ignored. correct your serializer to include the `blogpost` field:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.Field(source='blogpost.title')
    blogpost = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'content', 'post', 'blogpost')
```

now when you create a post request, the `blogpost` field should contain the `id` of the blog post to which you're attaching this comment.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Quick side question: In the form to post a comment, is there a way to make the blogpost field non-editable? When I set it to read_only=True in the serializer I get errors again.

Comment: For post requests it must remain editable, but you can use different serializers for different request methods. So for instance you can create a new `CommentUpdateSerializer` with the field `blogpost` being read-only, and then override in your view the `get_serializer_class` method, check the request method, and return the appropriate class. For post requests the normal `CommentSerializer`, for put and patch requests the `CommentUpdateSerializer` class.