# Django Rest Framework Integrity Error on save() with is_valid() returning true

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

**UPDATE** Issue was that I was not correctly applying migrations after changing the model to allow null/blank values.

**Original Post**
I'm using Django-rest-framework to enable tagging data during playback of Vimeo videos. I've built an endpoint at `/watchtape/videotojam/` and am using jquery to post to the endpoint using the current time of the video as the `start_time` VideoToJam field.
I'm getting an `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: player_list_videotojam.video_id may not be NULL`
exception thrown when the view calls `serializer.save()`, even though `serializer.is_valid()` returns True.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since the video foreign key relationship is created with `blank=True, null=True` and the serializer representation indicates that video is not a required field.

This seems to be related to [IntegrityError in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559435/integrityerror-in-django-rest-framework)
however the fix of adding `video = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` to the serializer throws `AssertionError: Relational field must provide a`queryset`argument, or set read_only=True` and when I set `read_only=True` the IntegrityError exception returns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Serializer**

```
class VideoToJamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoToJam
        fields = ('id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'video', 'jam', 'timecode_url')
```

**Model**

```
class VideoToJam(models.Model):
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                              validators=[_timecode_validator])
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                            validators=[_timecode_validator], 
                            blank=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, blank=True, null=True)
    jam = models.ForeignKey(Jam, null=True, blank=True)
    timecode_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Video(models.Model):
    SITES = (
             ('vimeo', '''http://vimeo.com'''),
             ('youtube', '''http://youtube.com'''),
             ('', 'unknown'),
            )

    url = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    site = models.CharField(max_length = 7, choices=SITES)
    #URL for vimeo embed code
    player_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return(reverse("video_player", kwargs={'video_id':self.id}))

    def __str__(self):
        return("Video {0}".format(self.id))
```

**View**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def viewvideotojam_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = VideoToJamSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    videotojams = VideoToJam.objects.all()
    serializer = VideoToJamSerializer(videotojams, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Urls**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^videotojam/$', views.viewvideotojam_list, name='videotojam_list'),
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `blank=True, null=True` should be enough. The `null=True` causes a schema change, did you generate a migration for it?

If you're on Django prior to 1.7 and you're using South, you should run `migrate` and `schemamigration`.

If you're on Django 1.7 or greater, you should run `migrate` and `makemigrations`.

Comment: I'm using django 1.7, but I hadn't correctly setup migrations, after a makemigration and migration this now works. Thanks!